# некорректное отображение информации в dataGridView

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, datagridview

у меня есть C# .NET Framework приложение, которое работает с JSON файлами.
Вот метод, который получает данные из JSON файла:

```
        public virtual Hashtable Load()
        {
            try
            {
                var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(FileName);

                var userProblems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Hashtable>(jsonString);
                return userProblems;
            }
            catch { return null; }
        }
```

Также я имею dataGridView, в который вывожу данные с помощью этого кода:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Show all user problems in dataGridView.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="date">date of concrete problem</param>
        /// <param name="rowIndex">row index in dataGridView</param>
        private void ShowProblems(KeyValuePair<string, JToken> date, ref short rowIndex)
        {

            var userProblems = (JObject)date.Value;
            //TODO: creating new field for problem.
            _problemsList.Rows.Add(date.Key);

            //depending of every problem status, give to check box needed value.
            if (userProblems["issolved"].ToString() == "False")
                _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value = false;
            else
                _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].Value = true;

            _problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = userProblems["text"].ToString();

            rowIndex++;
        }
```

Проблема в том, что в json файле у меня присутствует такой значок между словами:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть перенос строки. А в dataGridView у меня почему-то так отображается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема? может в коде я что-то не так делаю, или это в самой Visual Studio надо настраивать параметры? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207683/c-sharp-textbox-newline-problems) есть ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: Здравствуйте, попробовал вот так: ```_problemsList.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].Value = userProblems["text"] + Environment.NewLine + "some text";``` но ничего не изменилось - переноса строки нет. Также пробовал в ручную заменить в json файле на такое - "\r\n", но тоже не помогло

Comment: Ну вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514352/multiple-lines-in-a-datagridview-cell/16514393) точно ответ на ваш вопрос. (Сам проверил)

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам огромное, мне это помогло!=)